# How can I convert minutes to hours and seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

It's supposed to open in a pop-up text box but I want the user to be able to choose `h` or `s` and then there's another pop-up that gives the answer.

But nothing is working. This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javaScript">

var minutes = prompt("Enter number of minutes");
var answer = prompt("Enter h for hours or s for seconds");

function convertToHours(minutes) {
    hours = minutes/60;
    window.alert("There are " + hours + " hours in " + minutes + " minutes");
}

function convertToSeconds(minutes) {
    seconds = minutes*60;
    window.alert("There are " + seconds + " seconds in " + minutes + " minutes");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code looks fine, but you did not call a function inside the script tag. if you call and pass minutes fetched from the prompt then it will work. you do not need answer prompt.

Comment: How do I call a function and pass minutes fetched from the prompt? Sorry, I'm still really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="javaScript">

var minutes=prompt("Enter number of minutes");
var answer=prompt("Enter h for hours or s for seconds");

function convertToHours(minutes) {
    var hours=minutes/60;
    window.alert("There are " + hours + " hours in " + minutes + " minutes");
}

function convertToSeconds(minutes) {
    var seconds=minutes*60;
    window.alert("There are " + seconds + " seconds in " +minutes + " minutes");
}

if (answer === 'h') {
  convertToHours(minutes);
}else if(answer === 's'){
  convertToSeconds(minutes);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Please refer to the JavaScript section for an update. I am calling functions based on the answer and passing the minutes value while calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var minutes=prompt("Enter number of minutes");
    var answer = prompt("Enter h or s");
    
    function convertToHours(minutes) {
        hours=minutes/60;
        window.alert("There are " + parseInt(hours) + " hours in " + minutes + " minutes");
    }

    function convertToSeconds(minutes) {
        seconds=minutes*60;
        window.alert("There are " + seconds + " seconds in " +minutes + " minutes");
    }
    
    // just to check enter value is not a string
    if(isNaN(minutes/2)){
        window.alert("Enter number only in minutes");
     } else {
        switch(answer){
          case "h":
            convertToHours(minutes);
            break;
          case "s":
           convertToSeconds(minutes);
           break;
          default:
            window.alert("Enter valid choice either h or s only");
            break;
        }
      }
```

You just have to call both methods with the value of prompt. everything else in the code looks fine.

Just one suggestion always add js at end of the body or want to add it into the head then defer it.

Comment: Where does the user select hours or seconds?... And this is going to run both methods every time

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't call to your function:

```
if (minutes!= null) {
  // Do something or call your function in here
}
if (answer!= null) {
  // Do something or call your function in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToHours(minutes) {

var minutes = prompt("Enter number of minutes");

if (minutes != null && minutes != '') {
   // To get the number of hours from given minutes, divide the number of total minutes by 60 (minutes/60):

   var hours = minutes / 60;
   window.alert("There are " + hours + " hours in " + minutes + " minutes");

  }
}

function convertToSeconds(minutes) {
    var minutes = prompt("Enter number of minutes");
   // To get the number of seconds in given minutes, divide the number of multiply minutes by 60 (minutes * 60):

    if (minutes != null && minutes != '') {
        var seconds = minutes * 60;
        window.alert("There are " + seconds + " seconds in " +minutes + "  minutes");
    }
}
```

> Call your functions

```
convertToHours();
convertToMinutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to call the right method depending on whether the use selects `hours` or `seconds`

```html
    
<html>
<head>
<script language="javaScript">

var minutes = prompt("Enter number of minutes");
var answer = prompt("Enter h for hours or s for seconds");

if(answer == "h")
    convertToHours(minutes);
else if(answer == "s")
    convertToSeconds(minutes);
    
function convertToHours(minutes) {
    hours=minutes/60;
    window.alert("There are " + hours + " hours in " + minutes + " minutes");
}

function convertToSeconds(minutes) {
    seconds=minutes*60;
    window.alert("There are " + seconds + " seconds in " +minutes + " minutes");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```